# Similar and directly similar figures

Tags: geometry

What is the difference between similar and directly similar triangles. I googled it but did not find anything that I could understand.

please explain it to me with the help of diagram

Answer (score 2):

A triangle is similar to another if it can be translated ("picked up and moved"), rotated, "flipped", and grown/shrunken to fit into the other.

Directly similar means that one can fit into another without the need for "flipping" it. So, moving, rotating, or shrinking/stretching.

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Similar.html

Answer (score 2):

A similarity is a bijection of the plane onto itself which multiplies distances by a positive factor $r$ (the ratio of similarity).

A similarity is *direct* if it preserves orientation, *indirect* (or *opposite*) if it changes orientation. An simple example of an indirect similarity are *reflections*.